# Execution the .sh file in python

Tags: python, pycharm, command, sh

I have a file and its name is (Pro_data.sh) which contains these commands:

```
python preprocess.py dex

python preprocess.py lex

python process.py
```

I do not know how can I run the file in the python terminal (pycharm as an example).

I can run each command alone but I want to know the right way to run the .sh file for saving execution time.

Comment: if you have python installed and the files in your Pro_data.sh takes care of all the setup needs, then sure you can run the file. At least give it a try to find the errors. for example, to run this file on mac os(with sufficient access) you would go with $sh Prod_data.sh

Comment: my os is windows, and there is no error in the code but I want to know how to run .sh in python terminal

Comment: in that case, there should have been a .bat file or you can create one with the name Pro_data.bat and put those three commands in it.

Comment: Ok, I create one manually with extension .bat. I ran it with { python Pro_data.bat } in terminal but I got the error of {SyntaxError: invalid syntax} for {python preprocess.py dex}

Comment: just Prod_data.bat and then it should execute your three commands

Comment: great! I added this to the answer so that it can help future SO readers.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

main.py

```
import os
os.system('sh x.sh')
```

x.sh

```
python test2.py
```

test2.py

```
print('up')
```

output from main.py

```
up
```

Comment: Yes . but in the project  I want to execute. I have the files:( main.py,  preprocess.py, process.py and  Pro_data.sh . //   main .py has already many lines of the code, so where can I write{ import os
os.system(' Pro_data.sh')}

Answer (score 1):

.sh is a mac/Linux shell. for windows: create one with the name Pro_data.bat and put those three commands in it, and run Prod_data.bat
**Prod_data.bat**

```
python preprocess.py dex

python preprocess.py lex

python process.py
```